# How to make it so only ints from the array can be chosen? Also how to find biggest integer from integers chosen?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I am making a program that prompts the user for 3 integers and prints out the biggest one chosen. I am stuck with 2 problems at the moment. I would like to know how I can make the program so that the user can only choose integers from the array. I would also like to know how to find and print out the biggest integer from the ones that the user chose. I'm quite new to programming so all feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Lab14C // name of class file 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " "); 
        }

        System.out.println("\n"); 
        Scanner array1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your first integer? ");
        double array11 = array1.nextInt();

        Scanner array2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your second integer? ");
        double array22 = array2.nextInt();

        Scanner array3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your third integer? ");
        double array33 = array3.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Why are you creating three separate `Scanner`s instead of reusing the same one? 2) Why are you reading in `int`s and storing them in a `double`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to force a user to input an element. Few things you could do is :

- Tell the user he has to select a number in a particular range.
- Keep the input statement in a loop. If the entered element exists in array , go ahead. Else tell the user to enter again.

Printing the biggest integer can be done using `Math.max(double,double)` function. For three elements you can try `System.out.println("Max of three is "+Math.max(array11,Math.max(array22,array33)))`

You can do it yourself if you want instead of built in function like:

```
if(array1>array2&&array1>array3)
//print max as array1
else if(array2>array1&&array2>array3)
//print max as array2
else //print array3 as max
```

Also change your element types to `int` as you are reading integer.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no need to create a new Scanner all the time.
Just create one Scanner (which I would just call input or scanner or something that makes sense).

2) If you're reading int's why are you storing them in doubles?

3) To check for a certain condition you use `if(*condition*) { /*do something */ }`. So if you want to check if x is smaller than y you do `if(x < y) { /* do something */ }`. (In your case you'll want to check if current input is greater than biggest input and if so set the biggest input to current input.)

4) For a sorted array you can use Arrays.binarySearch(array, elementToSearch) which will return the index of the element when found, or a negative number if not found (the negative number is `(-(insertionPoint)-1)`). (So you can check if the number entered by the user is in the array and keep asking for a new number if is not.)

Answer (score 0):

1) `How I can make the program so that the user can only choose integers from the array.?`

You are declaring `array` variable as `int[]` so it stores only integer values. Whenever you retrives the value from this `array`,  it returns `int` value only so you don't have to worry about it.

2)`how to find and print out the biggest integer from the ones that the user chose.?`

To find the maximum or minimum from a set of values, Java provide a function name `Math#max()`. You can use it like this :

```
int maxValue = Math.max(Math.max(array11,array22),array33);
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) is the doc for Math library.